# Звук не проигрывается при запуске загрузки внутри setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

Когда я пытаюсь вызвать метод `loadSound` внутри `setOnClickListener` ,звук не появляется, но когда я его взываю в методе `onCreateView` или `onStart`, тогда  звук появляется и все отлично работает.
В чем тут проблема и есть ли какой нибудь способ вызвать метод только при нажатии на кнопки ?

и даже я вызвал метод `setOnLoadCompleteListener` внутри `setOnClickListener` и все равно не помогло.

```
public class InsectsFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    private int mBeeSound;


    public InsectsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_insects, container, false);



        Sound.mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                Sound.loaded = true;

            }
        });

        ImageButton beeBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBee);

        beeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Sound.mStreamID > 0) {
                    Sound.mSoundPool.stop(Sound.mStreamID);
                }
           mBeeSound = Sound.loadSound(getContext(), "bee.mp3");



                if (Sound.loaded) {
                    Sound.playSound(mBeeSound);
                    Snackbar.make(view, R.string.Bee, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), R.string.Bee, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в том, что вы пытаетесь запустить проигрывание до окончания его загрузки. Т.е. вам надо в onClick запустить загрузку звука, установить слушатель окончания и в нём уже запускать проигрывание. Код не тестировал, что за `Sound` я не знаю, но выглядеть должно как-то так:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_insects, container, false);

    ImageButton beeBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBee);

    beeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Sound.mStreamID > 0) {
                Sound.mSoundPool.stop(Sound.mStreamID);
            }


    Sound.mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            Sound.loaded = true;

            if (Sound.loaded) {
                Sound.playSound(mBeeSound);
                Snackbar.make(view, R.string.Bee, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), R.string.Bee, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
       mBeeSound = Sound.loadSound(getContext(), "bee.mp3");

    return view;
}
```

И отформатируйте код в вопросе - очень сложно в нём в таком виде разобраться.